# For discrete group $G$ and $H\leq G$. Show that $G$ also satisfies the Folner condition if $H$ satisfies it and $[G:H]<\infty$.

Tags: functional-analysis, group-theory, geometric-group-theory, amenability, geometric-functional-analysis

A finitely generated group $G=\langle S \rangle$ is said to have the Folner condition if $\forall \varepsilon>0$, there exists a finite subset $F\subset G$ such that
$$\#((S\cup S^{-1})F\setminus F)<\varepsilon\# F,$$
where $\#S$ is the cardinality of a set $S$. Or equivalently, $\forall\varepsilon>0$, for any finite $T\subset G$, there exists a finite $F\subset G$ such that
$$\#(TF\setminus F)<\varepsilon\#F.$$

Let $G$ be a discrete group and let H be a subgroup of $G$. Suppose that the index $[G:H]$ is finite and that $H$ satisfies the Folner condition. Prove that $G$ also satisfies the Folner condition.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: I have shown that if $T\subset H$, then it is trivial. So I am thinking of considering the case where $T\nsubseteq H$ and show the existence of $F\subset G$ satisfying the inequality.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some ideas. Let  $S$ be a generating set of $G$, and let  $\{t_i: 1 \le i \le n \}$ be a set of left coset representatives of $H$ in $G$. For $g \in G$, denote the unique $t_i$ with $gH = t_iH$ by $\bar{g}$.

Now let $T = \{\overline{st_i}^{-1}st_i : s \in S \cup S^{-1}, 1 \le i \le n \}$. Then $T$ generates $H$ by a result of Schreier.

Now, given $\epsilon > 0$, choose $F$ as a corresponding Fölner set for $H$ with respect to the generating set $T$. Then $\cup_{i=1}^n t_iF$ is a Fölner set for $G$ with respect to $S$.